# LINQ query for subset of two parallel arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on an application that uses a lot of X,Y spatial information.

Given two parallel arrays, one representing the X values and the other the Y values, **is there a way to select a subset from both arrays?**  The subset is determined by using a starting and stopping value in the x-values array.

Here's an example of two parallel arrays.

```
double[] xs = new double[] { 
    0.0, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16,
    0.2, 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 0.36,
    0.4, 0.44, 0.48, 0.52, 0.56,
    0.6, 0.64, 0.68, 0.72, 0.76,
    0.8, 0.84, 0.88, 0.92
};
double[] ys = new double[] {
    0.0152, 0.1434, 0.1647, 0.3800,
    0.7880, 0.0488, 1.0060, 0.2710,
    0.0363, 0.4321, 0.5573, 0.2192,
    0.6341, 0.5181, 0.9546, 0.8275,
    0.5567, 0.9870, 0.8895, 0.3423,
    0.6061, 0.1507, 0.7841, 0.6512
};
```

Suppose I wanted a subset of both x values and y values where x is greater than or equal to 0.1 and less than or equal to 0.2.  The result of such a subset should be two parallel arrays:

```
double[] x_subset = new double[] {
    0.12, 0.16, 0.2
};
double[] y_subset = new double[] {
    0.3800, 0.7880, 0.0488
};
```

The x and y arrays will always have the same number of elements.

I've tried using Zip but that doesn't work.  Apart from using plain old loops, I can't think of anything else.  I am new to LINQ, though.

Comment: "I've tried using Zip but that doesn't work." What was the error message? Are you sure you are using C# 4 or newer? Have you remembered `using System.Linq`?

Comment: I didn't receive an error; it just doesn't work the way I thought it does.  Then again, I am quite new to LINQ, so maybe there's a hidden quality to Zip that I don't know.

Comment: It definitely works. You must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be something like this :

```
var zipped = xs.Zip(ys, (x, y) => new { x, y })
               .Where(coord => coord.x > 0.1 && coord.x <= 0.2);
```

By using available in 4.0 version available [Enumerable.Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd267698.aspx).

Comment: This is why I love C#.  Thank you!

Comment: @James By using `Select`:

`double x_subset = zipped.Select(z => z.x);` 
`double y_subset = zipped.Select(z => z.y);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ queries to select the elements that match.

```
x_subset = xs.Where(x => x >= .1 && x <= .2).ToArray();
y_subset = ys.Where(y => y >= .1 && y <= .2).ToArray();
```

(You could also use a `Func<double, bool> f = (a) => a >= .1 && a <= .2)` ) and pass that as an argument to .Where)

Comment: But isn't `y_subset` going to contain y values that are between 0.1 and 0.2?